# facing problem in connecting mongoDB using the mongoDB client

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am connecting mongodb using the mongodb client in my app.

'app.js' file.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animals', function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err

//   db.collection('mammals').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
//     if (err) throw err

//     console.log(result)
//   })
})
```

the issue is:

```
(node:16348) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is 
deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new 
parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
/home/amarjeet/Desktop/node2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:474
      throw err;
       ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on 
first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/amarjeet/Desktop/node2/node_modules/mongodb- 
core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> 
(/home/amarjeet/Desktop/node2/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:276:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ amarjeet/Desktop/node2/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:276:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

so this is the issue is shown on terminal and i have no idea how to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

> just add {useNewUrlParser: true } in connection

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animals', {useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err
//   db.collection('mammals').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
//     if (err) throw err

//     console.log(result)
//   })
})
```

Comment: now i am connection mongoose and the error is shown.

Comment: `const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animals',{ useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.connection.once('open',()=> console.log('CONNECTED'))
.on('error',(err)=>{
    console.log(`could not connect`,err)
});`

Comment: and the error is `could not connect { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]`

Comment: Can you start mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install MongoDB database server first in your system and start it.
if already installed:
check whether server is in start state. and Try connecting with mongo shell
and if server is also in start state:
than just put `{useNewUrlParser: true }` as mentioned by the @Vaghani Janak

Comment: bro now `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]` error is showing.  @Shubham Tiwari

Comment: **sudo service mongod status**  try this command see what is the errorr showing in mongod

Comment: thank you server was inactive and i am make server active by `sudo service mongod start`. thank you bro!